# How to Create Folders and Subfolders in %AppData%

Tags: vbscript, user-profile, appdata

First of all thank you very much for all the help I’ve found over 3 Vbscript that has save my life during this last six months.
I’m new to Vbscripting and I’m currently working on getting a Vbscript that create folders and copy a file at the same time overwrite that folder and file if they already exist
Folder  and subfolders to be created (Avaya) C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Roaming\Avaya\ Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5\
File from (Myfile.txt) C:\Myfile.txt to C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Roaming\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5\

I get “Path not found” error, but If I leave the path till (Avaya) it creates Avaya Folder but not it’s subfolders  C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Roaming\Avaya\

Here’s what I have and thank you in advance

```
Dim fso, vFolder
Set objFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objWShell = wScript.createObject("WScript.Shell")
usrName = objWShell.expandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vFolder = fso.CreateFolder("C:\Users\" & usrName & "\AppData\Roaming\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5\")
CreateFolderDemo = vFolder.Path
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some errors:

1. You declare `fso`, but you use `objFso`
2. You use `%USERNAME%` but you should consider `%APPDATA%` instead
3. You should use `OPTION EXPLICIT` to detect typos and undefined variables
4. You should make your code easier to read by dimming one variable at a time
5. `CreateFolder` doesn't create the entire tree, so you need to use `FolderExists`

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWShell
Set objWShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim appData
appData = objWShell.expandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
Dim objFso
Set objFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not objFso.FolderExists(appData + "\Avaya") Then
  objFso.CreateFolder appData + "\Avaya"
End If
If Not objFso.FolderExists(appData + "\Avaya\one-X Agent") Then
  objFso.CreateFolder appData + "\Avaya\one-X Agent"
End If
If Not objFso.FolderExists(appData + "\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5") Then
  objFso.CreateFolder appData + "\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5"
End If
```

Lastly, it's not clear why your solution needs to be in VBScript. It appears that your requirements are creating folders and copying files, which means, batch files would probably be a far more simpler.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `CreateFolder` does not create intermediate folders. The FSO doesn't have a method that does that. It might be easier to use `mkdir` like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim shl
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call shl.Run("%COMSPEC% /c mkdir ""%APPDATA%\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5""",0,true)
```